# I died in Nethack to Food Poisoning, despite having Poison Resistance

Tags: nethack

I was playing Nethack last night, and mind you, I'm a beginner. In a desperate attempt to get some food in me, I mashed the e button and hit a random key. Unfortunately, I downed a rotten newt corpse, became poisoned, and as a result, died from said food poisoning. I decided to read over my attributes when I noticed I had Poison Resistance. Yet, here I was, dead from food *poison*ing.

I asked about this in the Nethack IRC chat room. They stated that food poisoning wasn't the poison I thought it was, which would be a substance on a weapon or a trap. I brought it up with my friend, who reiterated the above points, even saying that poison would be something like eating even a fresh Water Moccasin corpse.

I understand that, within the context of Nethack, the developers may consider these two different methods of poison, and that poison resistance only works against one method over the other. However, being someone interested in Biology, I am intuitively using the real-world definition of poison in my approach to the game.

A poison is a substance that becomes harmful when ingested or inhaled or absorbed.
Venom is a substance that becomes harmful when injected directly into the skin. People use these words interchangeably in an informal context. You might hear someone say "Don't get close that to that snake! It's poisonous." but the correct biological definition is that it's venomous. The same goes for incorrect usages of the words venom and venomous.

I accept that food poisoning is a different kind of poisoning in Nethack, of which is not insured against by my poison resistance. But, to someone who approaches this game understanding the difference, this could be confusing, as the terms *are used incorrectly* to the real-world definitions.

So, my question here is, do you guys agree that Nethack uses these terms incorrectly *to the real-world definitions*, and that they have their own redefinition of the terms to exclude food poisoning from being combated by poison resistance? That's all I need to prove my case, that the definitions in Nethack are not the same as they are in real-life, and that I am not necessarily in the wrong for intuitively assuming food poisoning would be resisted.

As a suggestion, I think Nethack would benefit from renaming Food Poisoning to Food Sickness or the general words "Sickness" or "Illness".

Comment: NetHack is a world full of magic and legend, not a highly scientific simulation. In any case, voting to close this question as it is essentially a poll.

Comment: It's a question. The question is "Is Nethack's definition of Poison incorrect *to the real world definition*, which would have allowed my Poison Resistance to protect me from Food Poisoning?"

Comment: "Do you guys agree" is not really a question suitable for the stackexchange platform. It's the very definition of a subjective and argumentative question.

Comment: @Rauta Yet below you say "I realize that Nethack's Poison Resistance only works against some forms of poison. I just need some acknowledgement..." That doesn't sound like a question to me.

Comment: As you are asking for opinion rather than a solution to a problem, a game-related strategy or game information, this doesn't belong here, but rather in a discussion forum.

Comment: Yes, that's because the question is not in that section of text. The question is both stated below that and inferred from the text as a whole. In addition, the question "Do you guys agree?" is not *the question*, it's a confirmation alongside the question. The real-world definition of poison would include food poisoning. If Nethack used the real world definition, I would be protected. But, I wasn't, so is it true that Nethack uses their own definitions? That's the question. It's a simple yes or no.

Comment: @Rauta: No, the real-world definition of "poison" is a toxic compound. A potentially lethal microbial infection (like you'd get from spoiled food) is not "poisoning".

Comment: @Rauta This isn't a site about biology. It seems like a weird question anyway, when's the last time you've seen an actual wizard cast a spell to turn into a dragon in real life?

Comment: @Rauta you want people to agree (or disagree) with you about something. You were very clear that this is the question here. This kind of discussion does not belong here. Please see the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), it pretty explicitly forbids this: you should not ask a question where `there is no actual problem to be solved: "I'm curious if other people feel like I do."`

Answer (score 8):

"Food poisoning" is the generally accepted natural-language term for becoming ill due to eating spoiled food.

Even in the natural-language sense, it is recognized as quite different to being "poisoned" due to animal venom or some other poisonous compound.